# JsonSubTypes atributo name basado en enum

Tags: java, json, jackson

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "operator",
        visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LogicalCondition.class, name = "AND"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ComparisonCondition.class, name = "IS_DESCENDANT")
})
```

¿Como configurar el parámetro name, de la notación JsonSubTypes.Type, para que sea una de las opciones de la clase Operators, metodo enum?

```
public abstract class Operators {
    public enum LogicalOperators {
        AND, OR
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene porque el nombre tiene que ser una constante y los enumerados en verdad no son constantes por dentro. A parte de hacerlo como has indicado en el ejemplo, podrías añadir otro nivel de redirección para tener el valor de los enumerados como constantes.

Es decir, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
    public enum LogicalOperators {
        AND(Constantes.AND), OR(Constantes.OR);

        private String valor;

        private LogicalOperators(String valor) {
            this.valor = valor;
        }

        public class Constantes {
            public static final String AND = "AND";
            public static final String OR = "OR";
        }

    }
```

En otro archivo se usaría como:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "operator",
        visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LogicalCondition.class, name = LogicalOperators.Constantes.AND)
})
```

Lo que haces es crear un enumerado con valores explicitos. Pero para que no se tenga que poner sus valores como literales se declara una clase (interna al enumerado) que declara como constantes los posibles valores. Así se pueden usar las constantes donde solo se permitan constantes y los enumerados en los demás sitios estando seguros que ambos tendrán el mismo valor.